# Instantiating classes using Object Initializers

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm still quite new to C#, so I apologize if my title does not use the correct terms.

This question is merely a curiosity on my part but is it possible to turn this code

```
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
```

into something like this

```
var folderPicker = new FolderPicker() {
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
}
```

I tried it but VS19 doesn't like it. I'm just not sure if my syntax is wrong or if it's just not possible.

Thank you for any help you provide.

Comment: missing `;` in the end I think

Comment: @Antoine I just tried adding the `;` to the end and I get an error
"Semicolon after method or accessor block is not valid"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer). This way you can assign initial values to the parameters of the object when using any constructor.

Important to note, you can only do **assignment** but no function invocation using the above method. Also note that you should use `,` instead of `;` to separate the expressions inside the curly braces, and omit the one after the last expression.

An example would be like:

```
var Cat = new Animal(){ 
    Type = AnimalTypes.Cat, 
    Name = "Cecil", 
    Age = 3 
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That tells me why I only get an error on `FileTypeFilter.Add("*")`

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.filetypefilter) here, `FileTypeFilter` is an `IList` so you could try assigning it like `FileTypeFilter = new List<string>(){ "*" }`

Comment: @pappbence96 Thanks but it turns out that `FileTypeFilter` is readonly. It looks like I'm going to have to do this the old fashioned way.